# Is it possible to change cell color in dataset without excel worksheet?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm using a dataset without a excel worksheet and need the color of the cells changed, is there a way to do that? I only find solutions involving using an excel worksheet.

```
Dim dsTemp As System.Data.DataSet
dsTemp = CType(Me.uwgGeneratedMatrix.DataSource, System.Data.DataSet)
If dsTemp.Tables(0).Columns.Contains("VerticalID") Then
    dsTemp.Tables(0).Columns.Remove("VerticalID")
End If
If dsTemp.Tables(0) IsNot Nothing Then
    For index As Integer = dsTemp.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Dim dsRow As System.Data.DataRow = dsTemp.Tables(0).Rows(index)
        Dim value As Object = dsRow.Item(0)
        If Not Microsoft.VisualBasic.IsDBNull(value) AndAlso String.Compare(value.ToString, "ColDes", True) = 0 Then
            dsTemp.Tables(0).Rows.Remove(dsRow)
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Your question is nonsensical. It's like asking if you can change the colour of your name. A `DataSet` simply stores data. Data doesn't have a colour. Colour is a visual thing. It only applies to the UI in which the data is displayed. It is possible to store colour data and then use that in the UI when the rest of the data is displayed but then the colour data would be stored like any other data and you'd have to write appropriate code to use in an appropriate way.

Comment: What exactly is `uwgGeneratedMatrix`? If that's a control used to display the data then that is where you'd be using colour.